# How can I add GeoDjango to my alpine dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gdal, alpine-linux

I'm want to add GeoDjango (needed dep.: GDAL, GEOS, PROJ.4) to my docker alpine image. My Dockerfile has already a requirements.txt-file setup.

I looked up e.g. GDAL on PyPi and found four dependencies for GDAL:

"libgdal (3.0.1 or greater) and header files (gdal-devel)
numpy (1.0.0 or greater) and header files (numpy-devel) (not explicitly required, but many examples and utilities will not work without it)"

So I think I need to add: numpy, numpy-devel, libgdal and gdal-devel?

I added these dependencies to my requirements.txt-file but I get the message that numpy is required to proceed with GDAL.

So I added numpy to my dockerfile directly

Dockerfile
...

```
 COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
 RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client jpeg-dev
 RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
       gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev musl-dev zlib-dev
 RUN pip install numpy==1.14.3 libgdal==3.0.1
 RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
 RUN apk del .tmp-build-deps
```

...

requirements.txt
 ...

```
 GDAL>=3.0.1,<3.1.0
```

...

This is the error when I try to build my docker image "docker-compose build":
...

```
Step 7/18 : RUN pip install numpy==1.14.3 libgdal==3.0.1
 ---> Running in ffaa7d1b9ad6
Collecting numpy==1.14.3
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/2b/497c2bb7c660b2606d4a96e2035e92554429e139c6c71cdff67af66b58d2/numpy-1.14.3.zip (4.9MB)
Collecting libgdal==3.0.1
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libgdal==3.0.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libgdal==3.0.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.1.1, however version 19.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install numpy==1.14.3 libgdal==3.0.1' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/gdal